# Unexpected collision with std::hash

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hash, hash-collision, stdhash

I know hashing infinite number of string into 32b int must generate collision, but I expect from hashing function some nice distribution.

Isn't it weird that these 2 strings have the same hash?

```
size_t hash0 = std::hash<std::string>()("generated_id_0");
size_t hash1 = std::hash<std::string>()("generated_id_1");
//hash0 == hash1
```

I know I can use `boost::hash<std::string>` or others, but I want to know what is wrong with `std::hash`. Am I using it wrong? Shouldn't I somehow "seed" it?

Comment: @relaxxx: MSVC10 will probably be the last to provide a full c++11 implementation (if they ever will). if you want a working implementation, the most complete one is clang. you can also try the more popular gcc.

Comment: VC10 *does* have a specific implementation for string.

Comment: The old standard didn't define specific specializations for types that are usually pointers, but the newer standard requires specializations for things like char*, std::string, etc.  I was just saying to @Dani that there is a specialization implemented in VS2010 for std::string.

Comment: @Dani: as much as I like clang, I think gcc is a bit ahead on C++11 features, though again, it's hard to say for sure as neither fully implement what the other covers.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: If you look at implementation status pages, you see that clang is far ahead.

Comment: @Dani: Where did you get that strange idea ? Comparing [Clang 3.0](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) with [GCC 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html), out of 13 items that differentiate them, Clang implement 4 and gcc the other 9. (Clang: n2439, n2258, n2341 and n1986; gcc: n2672, n2927, n2764, n2235, n2170, n2765, n2253, n2544 and n2427)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your usage of `std::hash`. The problem is that the specialization `std::hash<std::string>` provided by the standard library implementation bundled with Visual Studio 2010 only takes a subset of the string's characters to determine the hash value (presumably for performance reasons). Coincidentally the last character of a string with 14 characters is not part of this set, which is why both strings yield the same hash value.

As far as I know this behaviour is in conformance with the standard, which *demands* only that multiple calls to the hash function with the same argument must always return the same value. However, the probability of a hash collision *should* be minimal. The VS2010 implementation fulfills the mandatory part, yet fails to account for the optional one.

For details, see the implementation in the header file `xfunctional` (starting at line 869 in my copy) and §17.6.3.4 of the C++ standard ([latest public draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)).

If you absolutely need a better hash function for strings, you should implement it yourself. It's actually [not that hard](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html).

Answer (score 11):

The exact hash algorithm isn't specified by the standard, so the results
will vary.  The algorithm used by VC10 doesn't seem to take all of the
characters into account if the string is longer than 10 characters; it
advances with an increment of `1 + s.size() / 10`.  This is legal,
albeit from a QoI point of view, rather disappointing; such hash codes
are known to perform very poorly for some typical sets of data (like
URLs).  I'd strongly suggest you replace it with either a FNV hash or
one based on a Mersenne prime:

FNV hash:

```
struct hash
{
    size_t operator()( std::string const& s ) const
    {
        size_t result = 2166136261U ;
        std::string::const_iterator end = s.end() ;
        for ( std::string::const_iterator iter = s.begin() ;
              iter != end ;
              ++ iter ) {
            result = (16777619 * result)
                    ^ static_cast< unsigned char >( *iter ) ;
        }
        return result ;
    }
};
```

Mersenne prime hash:

```
struct hash
{
    size_t operator()( std::string const& s ) const
    {
        size_t result = 2166136261U ;
        std::string::const_iterator end = s.end() ;
        for ( std::string::const_iterator iter = s.begin() ;
              iter != end ;
              ++ iter ) {
            result = 127 * result
                   + static_cast< unsigned char >( *iter ) ;
        }
        return result ;
    }
};
```

(The FNV hash is supposedly better, but the Mersenne prime hash will be
faster on a lot of machines, because multiplying by 127 is often
significantly faster than multiplying by 16777619.)

Comment: thank you very much, I wish i can accept more than one correct answer :)

Comment: @relaxxx: of late, CityHash and MurmurHash seem to be getting quite popular too. You might also want to give them a try.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'll have to look into them if I get the chance.  I did extensive measurements, with 20 or so popular hashs, but that was about 20 years ago.  These two were the winners then, but obviously, things could easily have changed since then.

Comment: Note that the 32-bit FNV Hash parameters are used in the above example, for the 64-bit ones see http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/index.html#FNV-param

Comment: Sometimes I think Microsoft get their stuff made by interns.

Comment: JFYI: The latest Visual Studio (2017, not sure about the 2015) has FNV hash for std::hash<std::string>.

Answer (score 3):

You should likely get different hash values. I get different hash values (GCC 4.5):

## hashtest.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
size_t hash0 = std::hash<std::string>()("generated_id_0");
size_t hash1 = std::hash<std::string>()("generated_id_1");
std::cout << hash0 << (hash0 == hash1 ? " == " : " != ") << hash1 << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
# g++ hashtest.cpp -o hashtest -std=gnu++0x
# ./hashtest
16797002355621538189 != 16797001256109909978
```

Comment: he is using MSVC, unfortunately for him :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not seed hashing function, you can just salt "them" at most.

The function is used in the right way and this collision could be just fortuitous.

You cannot tell whether the hashing function is  not evenly distributed unless you perform a massive test with random keys.

Answer (score 0):

The TR1 hash function and the newest standard define proper overloads for things like strings.  When I run this code using std::tr1::hash (g++ 4.1.2), I get different hash values for these two strings.